# How to mock out a Blazor component rendered within another component?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, blazor, bunit

Suppose I have the below `Parent.razor` component:

```
<div>
    <span>Below is a child component.</span>
    <Child/>
</div>
```

Where `Child` is a very complex component `Child.razor`.

If I want to unit-test `Parent.razor`, how do I mock out `<Child/>` so that the test focuses on the `Parent` component alone? What libraries do I use?

Comment: Have you tried bUnit?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but bUnit is just a test framework and doesn't have mocking tools.

Comment: Mocking a component will require an `IChild` (or parent.child paramter) and some kind of injection.  It'll be difficult and probably not worth it... How do you envision the mocking api working?

Comment: An example api: Mock<Child>("replacement html")?

Comment: Well yes, something like that. I come from a react background. In react, we would use Jest.Mock() to replace some component with something like <div>{children}</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you design your `Parent` component such that it's Child components can be replaced at runtime (e.g. through a RenderFragment parameter), you cannot replace a component at runtime, and thus not mock it.

There is a change coming in .net 5 that will allow bUnit to do it, but for the current version of Blazor it's not possible.

Comment: People reading this answer might also be interested in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/issues/388) opened a few days ago.

Comment: Correct, we are working on enabling this scenario. Thanks for sharing the link @J.P.tenBerge